# terminating: libs to export not found on above classpath: /sikulixlibs/windows/libs64

Tags: java, eclipse, sikuli

I am writing sikuli scripts in Eclipse..

I have added `sikulixapi-1.1.0.jar and sikuli-3.0.0` in Eclipse Project build path.

I am getting following error:

```
*** classpath dump end
[error] RunTimeINIT:  *** terminating: libs to export not found on above classpath: /sikulixlibs/windows/libs64
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

I have added folderpath where the jar is there, i have added in Environment Variable as Path

How to resolve this issue?

Here is my code..

```
import org.sikuli.script.Button;
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
import org.sikuli.script.Key;
import org.sikuli.script.Match;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;
import org.sikuli.script.Keys;

public class test {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{
                Screen s = new Screen();
                s.click("C:\\Users\\eguru\\Desktop\\sikuli\\step1.png");
                s.click("C:\\Users\\eguru\\Desktop\\sikuli\\step2.png");
                s.click("C:\\Users\\eguru\\Desktop\\sikuli\\field38.png");    
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                s.type("D");                
                s.type(Key.TAB);
                if(s.exists("C:\\Users\\eguru\\Desktop\\sikuli\\warningOkbutton.png")!=null){
                    s.click("C:\\Users\\eguru\\Desktop\\sikuli\\warningOkbutton.png");
                }
                s.click("C:\\Users\\eguru\\Desktop\\sikuli\\step3.png");                
                s.click("C:\\Users\\eguru\\Desktop\\sikuli\\lastnametextfield.png");
                s.type("a",Key.CTRL);
                s.type(Key.DELETE);
                s.type("Last Name for CTR");                
                s.click("C:\\Users\\eguru\\Desktop\\sikuli\\firstnametextfield.png");
                s.type("a",Key.CTRL);
                s.type(Key.DELETE);
                s.type("First Name for CTR");
                s.click("C:\\Users\\eguru\\Desktop\\sikuli\\step4.png");
                s.click("C:\\Users\\eguru\\Desktop\\sikuli\\step0.png");

                String typeoffiling = "C:\\Users\\eguru\\Desktop\\sikuli\\typeoffilingcheckbox.png";
                while(s.exists(typeoffiling)== null){
                    s.wheel(Button.WHEEL_DOWN, 5);

                }
                s.click(typeoffiling);
                //s.click("C:\\Users\\eguru\\Desktop\\sikuli\\typeoffilingcheckbox.png"); 
                Thread.sleep(10000);                
                String saveButton = "C:\\Users\\eguru\\Desktop\\sikuli\\savebutton.png";
                while(s.exists(saveButton)== null){
                    s.wheel(Button.WHEEL_DOWN, 5);                  
                }
                s.click(saveButton);
        }
        catch(FindFailed e){
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: did you solve it? I have the same problem.

Comment: I had bit9 issue.. once it is enabled, it is working for me

Answer (score 2):

You have to double click the .jar.
There's a setup over there. I selected pack 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

1.Download this jar file, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sikuli/SikuliX-Setup/1.1.0

2. Double click and select your options
3. I will generate sikulixapi.jar and sikulilibswin-1.1.0
4. link those jars with java build path -> classpath.
5. Ctrl+B build all

I hope your issues has been solved.

Answer (score -1):

For people who do not have the solution of our partner  alansiqueira27 (that my example), they should be downloaded directly,
sikulixlibswin-1.1.1.jar (last version windows)

[image]
with these lib should not have problems in windows and that is the link:

https://jar-download.com/cache_jars/com.sikulix/sikulixlibswin/1.1.1/jar_files.zip